# Reputation from documentation

Tags: discussion, support, documentation

Is it possible that you can gain reputation in **Documentation** the new functionality of Stack Overflow, and if so, how can I get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the documentation [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation):

> The existing Q&A reputation and badge systems have been extended to Documentation.
>   You still have one number, your total reputation, which is a measure of how much you've helped your fellow developers.

Reputation is earned by:

- contributing to Documentation that is cited in answers
- contributing to examples that are upvoted
- having your changes reviewed and approved

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Details here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation